# how to Find all T-invariant subspaces of T?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let T be the linear transformation on R2 which is represented by the matrix

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    1 & 4 \\
    2 & 3  \\
      \\
    \end{matrix}
$$
 Find all T-invariant subspaces.

I understand that span 
 $
    \begin{matrix}
    1  \\
    1   \\
      \\
    \end{matrix}
$
is one of them- how do I find the rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tht matrix has two eigenvalues: $5$ and $-1$. An eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $5$ is the one that you mentioned: $(1,1)$. An eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $-1$ is $(2,-1)$. Therefore, the invariant subspaces are:

- $\{0\}$;
- $\mathbb R(1,1)$;
- $\mathbb R(2,-1)$;
- $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: Hi , thanks! but why R2. ?

Comment: Because $T.\mathbb R^2\subset\mathbb R^2$. Which definition of “invariant subspace” do you use?

Comment: how did you understand that?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: why  the subspace  R2 is also a T-invariant subspace? how do you kmow that for all vector "u" in R2 t(u) is also in R2 ?

Comment: Again, which definition of “invariant subspace” do you use?